# How to see the exact unmasked request in vue.js at the prod environment?

Tags: javascript, rest, vue.js, axios, production-environment

I have a rest-api running on mysite.com:8084. When I send a request, by using axios in Vue.js, I get HTTP 404 error all the time. There is no problem with my localhost.

When I check my prod.env.js, it looks ok. When I try to reach the api from my browser (mysite.com:8084/metadata/countries), it is ok also.

Here is my prod.env.js:

```
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"',
  ENV_CONFIG: '"prod"',
  BASE_API: '"mysite.com:8084"' (with http:// prefix)
}
```

And this is my dev settings:

```
    proxyTable: {
      '/api': {
        target: '://localhost:8084', (with http prefix)
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
          '^/api': ''
        }
      }
    }

  const req1 = {
    url: '/api/metadata/countries',
    method: 'GET'
  }
  const req2 = {
    url: '/metadata/countries',
    method: 'GET'
  }

  console.log('URL is ' + axios.defaults.baseURL)
  // this line prints: "URL is ://mysite.com:8084" (with http prefix)

  console.log('query for req1')
  axios(req1)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('req1: is OK')
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('req1: error' + err))

  console.log('query for req2')
  axios(req2)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('req2: is OK')
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('req2: error' + err))
```

I get a HTTP 404 error from the service in both with req1 and req2.

Is there a way to see the exact endpoint address that gets 404?

So any help will be very appreciated.

Thank you...

Comment: Open google chrome devtools, and check the network tab

Comment: The network request is masked as mysite.com/metadata/countries

Comment: What do you mean it's *"masked"*? Do you mean you have some kind of proxy? If so, does *that* have logs you can look at?

Comment: I mean that I see the request as proxied mysite.com/metadata/countries